# Knife bootstrap gets stuck

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to run the following command to bootstrap a node

```
knife bootstrap -V -V yy.yy.xx.xx --ssh-user root --ssh-password 'XXXX' --sudo --use-sudo-password --node-name node-test --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_apache2]'
```

On the chef management console I can see the node getting registered (though with no information about the node) but chef client doesn't run on the target and I don't understand what logs can I refer. Chef server logs (chef-server-ctl tail) doesn't show anything specific.

I am new to chef where can I look for logs or what's happening, I have separate machines for workstation , chef server and chef client.

All the servers are behind the same proxy.

Comment: What is the output of your knife command (1st thing to look at), what are the chef-client logs on the target machine (yy.yy.xx.xx) 
 in var/log/chef/client.log ? (Chef server logs won't help you, Chef is a pull model, the client does everything, the server authenticate and serve the cookbooks to the clients on request mainly)

Comment: I dont have client.log file. and the knife command also is not giving any output on console. It's just stuck there without any output. On management console I can see the node getting registered without FQDN and other details but the runlist is getting associated with node associated as per the command.

Comment: What is your knife.rb content ? (you can obfuscate ips/servers names)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to get this fixed I changed the order of the command (there was another stack overflow thread for this that I can't remember right know). Here it is how my command now looks like:
*knife bootstrap windows winrm  **--node-name chef-node-3** -x  -P  --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_iis]'*

Also, I've gotten other issue by running directly using the SDK shortcut. Instead use the a administrator powershell session to execute the knife commands.